# What happens to Leg Eater if you banish the Grimm Troupe before he goes to Divine?

Tags: hollow-knight

See title. Does he get any special dialog if you do this? Only got this idea AFTER I defeated the Nightmare King, so I'm curious to know if he says anything special when you go up to him with all three unbreakable charms.

Answer (score 3):

He doesn't have any special dialog, he just continues on same as before.